# How to use Redux state in _app.tsx (NextJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js

This is the code to my _app.tsx

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import AppNav from '../components/AppNav'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { store } from '../store'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { RootState } from '../store'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {

  const user = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.user.value)

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <div className='global_container'>
        <AppNav />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </div>
    </Provider>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

In the code, I am trying to use the user redux state inside _app.tsx, but it gives me an error: Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a Provider.

How can I access the redux state inside _app.tsx? This is nextjs by the way.

Comment: Make an abstraction (as only children of the provider will get access to the values). So you can return global container as a separate const (just put it above the return and call it inside the provider)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your component is not connected to the store. Normally this package https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper is used to wrap next.js. Once you created wrapper, you have to wrap _app.jx

```
export default wrapper.withRedux(MyApp);
```

Now you can use `useSelector` to access store within any component

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
```